# JS: Driver code returns false and I'm not sure why?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a practice exercise as a review before I start Dev Bootcamp, and even though my driver code looks like it should be correct, it keeps returning false instead of true.

Specifically, the code

```
greg.greet()
```

returns

```
"Hello, Greg Varias! Glad to have another Island Fox! We'll see you in Summer 2014!"
```

but the code

```
greg.greet() === "Hello, Greg Varias! Glad to have another Island Fox! We'll see you in Summer 2014!";
```

returns

```
false
```

I apologize if there is an obvious answer that I'm just not seeing, but I'm new to programming and I've exhausted my google searching ability and other resources. Any help is very much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
function Cohort(cohortName, timeFrame){
  this.name = cohortName;
  this.time = timeFrame;
} 

function Student(studentName, cohortName){
  this.studentName = studentName;
  this.cohortName = cohortName;
  this.greet = greet
}

var greet = function(){
    console.log("Hello, " + this.studentName + "! Glad to have another " + this.cohortName.name + "! We'll see you in " + this.cohortName.time +"!");
}

// driver code

var islandFox = new Cohort("Island Fox", "Summer 2014");
islandFox.name === "Island Fox" //true
islandFox.time === "Summer 2014" //true

var greg = new Student("Greg Varias", islandFox); //undefined 
greg.cohortName.name === "Island Fox" //true
greg.cohortName === islandFox // true

console.log(greg.cohortName) //{ name: 'Island Fox', time: 'Summer 2014' }

greg.greet() === "Hello, Greg Varias! Glad to have another Island Fox! We'll see you in Summer 2014!" //false
greg.greet() //Hello, Greg Varias! Glad to have another Island Fox! We'll see you in Summer 2014!
```

//driver code on line 98 still returning false, even though greg.greet() on line 99 seems to print the exact phrase perfectly. ??

Again, any help at all is very much appreciated and constructive criticism is welcome. I'm still learning, and I can't learn if I keep doing things the wrong way. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

because greet does not return a string! It returns nothing back

```
console.log(greg.greet())  //undefined
```

Now if the function were

```
var greet = function(){
    return ("Hello, " + this.studentName + "! Glad to have another " + this.cohortName.name + "! We'll see you in " + this.cohortName.time +"!");
}
```

your check would be true.

Comment: i.e., printing something to the console is not the same as returning it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I'm still getting the hang of when to use return vs. print/puts/console.log but I'll do some more studying. Thanks again!